# Is it possible to display an external website using <link> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I import a website using the < link > tag, will I be able to display it's contents into some element of my HTML page? The website I am trying to access has it's X-Frame-Options set to 'DENY'.

As per my understanding, such websites cannot be framed to prevent clickjacking. At I higher level, I believe this is a security restriction set to the website which I cannot modify at my end.

What I am currently trying is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="thisdiv">Hi</div>
      <script>
         // Handle Loaded Templates.
         function templatesLoaded(event) {
           console.log('Templates loaded.');
         }

         // Handle Errors.
         function templatesFailed(event) {
           console.log('Templates could not be loaded.');
         }
      </script>
      <link rel="import" href="https://someurl" onload="templatesLoaded(event)" onerror="templatesFailed(event)">
   </body>
</html>
```

I wish to know whether there is any way I can display the contents of the website into some element on my page in the templatesLoaded method.

Open for any suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: Just like Ajax `link rel="import"` works only for the current domain or another domain that has explicitly allowed this via CORS policy, it will not work as a general solution.

Comment: More here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I am stuck with how to display the entire content of the page instead of just a particular section of the page using 'querySelector' I am unable to select entire content of the imported html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe tag to display another webpages to your webpage.
See this link... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp